# make the search bar input on a same line with the website logo and login button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How i can push the search bar to the top?

I want to make it in the same line with the Iread logo

I tried (margin-top 0px)  and margin-bottom but not work

```css
form.sbar input[type=text] {

  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.sbar button {
  margin-top:0px;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.sbar button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

form.sbar::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div> 
      <form class="sbar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
         </form>
   </div>
</center>
```

the image is in div and the search form in div
and they both in parent div

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voyFY.png)

Comment: Use the browser inspect element to find what occupy the blank space above. Then remove that space.

Comment: Also don't use `<center>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to control the parent div with some css rules use the css **flex** rule
your parent div css would be something like this :

```
.parentCssClass{display:flex;flex-direction:row;align-items:center;}
```